# Create user full privileges on mongodb v3.0

Tags: mongodb

I had create an  account on "admin" database with roles :

> `roles:["readWriteAnyDatabase","userAdminAnyDatabase","dbAdminAnyDatabase”,”root"]`

Is it an highest privileges account ?

If not which roles have I missing ?

I want this "admin" account can manage all the action on database mongo includes replicate set , sharding ...

Answer (score 0):

The privileges mentioned by you should manage all the actions on a single mongod instance. As you want to manage the replica set also, I would suggest you to add **clusterAdmin** privilege as well.

It potentially contains the clusterManager, clusterMonitor, and hostManager including dropping database action.

So, update the admin user with clusterAdmin role to get the absolute control on your mongod cluster.

ref: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/